# ECS Fargate Container Parameters not visible inside Fargate worker

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create fargate task inside the step function using AWS Cdk ecsRunTask. But the values I am passing inside the command of containerOverrides are not extrapolating in fargate worker.

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'Vpc', {
  isDefault: true,
});

const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'FargateCluster', { vpc });

const taskDefinition = new ecs.TaskDefinition(this, 'TD', {
  memoryMiB: '512',
  cpu: '256',
  compatibility: ecs.Compatibility.FARGATE,
});

const containerDefinition = taskDefinition.addContainer('TheContainer', {
  image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('foo/bar'),
  memoryLimitMiB: 256,
});

const riTask = new tasks.EcsRunTask(this, 'The task', {
      integrationPattern: IntegrationPattern.RUN_JOB,
      cluster: cluster,
      taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
      containerOverrides: [{
        containerDefinition: containerDefinition,
        command: ["/app/appName", "$.x", "$.y", "$.z"],
      }],
      launchTarget: new tasks.EcsFargateLaunchTarget(),
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not extrapolating"?

Comment: I am not getting actual value of x,y,z parameters. I am getting values of x,y,z as "$.x", "$.y", "$.z" in string.